# Why does JOptionPane show different output comparing to System.out.println();?

Tags: java, swing, formatting, joptionpane

I was trying to create a multiplication table using System.out.println(); and it was perfectly formatted ; however when I tried to change it to JOptionPane function , the results were dissatisfactory. Here is the System.out.println(); code:

```
public class Problem {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        String output = "   Multiplication Table\n";
        output+= "  ------------------------------------\n";
        output+=" |   ";
        for(int j = 1;j<=9;j++)
            output+= j +"   ";
        output+= "\n";
        for(int i = 1 ; i<=9;i++){
            output+= i + "|";
            for(int  j = 1;j<=9;j++){
                output+=String.format("%4d", i * j);
            } 
            output+="\n";
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
 Multiplication Table
  ------------------------------------
 |   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
1|   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
2|   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18
3|   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27
4|   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36
5|   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
6|   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54
7|   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63
8|   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72
9|   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81
```

But Changing the *System.out.println(output);* to *JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);*
Gives the messed format,not well aligned, comparing to System.out.println();  I don't know how to copy the output from JOptionPane , but it looks something like this:

```
1| 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2| 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18
3| 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27
4| 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36
5| 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45
6| 6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54
7| 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63
8| 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72
9| 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

Comment: It's all about Fonts. The JOptionPane uses a Font that is not monospaced

Answer (score 2):

The issue is all about Fonts used, that the JOptionPane by default, does not display the text in a mono-spaced Font. You can see this for yourself by changing the Font used for the JOptionPane:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Problem {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        String output = "   Multiplication Table\n";
        output+= "  ------------------------------------\n";
        output+=" |   ";
        for(int j = 1;j<=9;j++)
            output+= j +"   ";
        output+= "\n";
        for(int i = 1 ; i<=9;i++){
            output+= i + "|";
            for(int  j = 1;j<=9;j++){
                output+=String.format("%4d", i * j);
            } 
            output+="\n";
        }
        System.out.println(output);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output); // non-monospaced font

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(output);
        textArea.setFocusable(false);
        textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
        textArea.setBorder(null);
        textArea.setBackground(null);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textArea); // displaying a monospaced font      
    }
}
```

This displays the 2nd JOptionPane as:

[image]

---

Note that the JOptionPane's fonts will be specified by whatever Look & Feel your program is using. You can tell the L&F to use a specific Font by using the UIManager to change the default message Font used by JOptionPane. For example, if you make the call below, then the JLabels used by JOptionPane (here the JOptionPane creates several rows of JLabel displayed in a JPanel using GridLayout) to whatever font desired:

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.messageFont", new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output); // non-monospaced font
```

Comment: Good day. Thanks for the answer. I got that problem from the "Intro to Java Programming"book and the original task was to use JOptionPane I tried anything but could'n get the right result.However the IMAGE FROM THE BOOK is from JOptionPane panel ! What's more the numbers are perfectly aligned. I don't have the answer on that solution therefore I came here...But I still do think that there must be smth to do with alignment according to the picture from the book.

Comment: @vm_1_r: Please see edit to the answer above. The differences may be due to whatever default version of the Look & Feel Java is using on that platform.

Comment: Thanks!  That seems  no longer to be INTRODUCTION to programming to me : )